# Find certain text and add css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a certain text like this:

```
<li>certain text</li>
```

Now I want to color the piece that says 'text'. With this I can find the complete text:

```
$(function() {
    var color = $('*:contains("text")');
    color.css("color", "red");
});
```

The problem is that this code turns the complete text in to red color. How do I get only the piece that says 'text' and do css on that part?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the `li` content as the browser can only apply style to elements, not words.

You may do that :

```
$('li:contains("text")').each(function(){
    var licontent = $(this).html();
    licontent = licontent.replace(new RegExp("text", "g"), '<span style="color:red">text</span>');
    $(this).html(licontent);
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/WspMa/)

Be careful with the `*` selector. You need to understand it would get you all parents of the `li`, including the document...

Comment: Note that the `replace` method with a string as first parameter only replaces the first occurance in the string, so you would need to use a reglar expression if there can be more than one occurance.

Comment: Or use the common trick of `string.split("replace this").join("with this")`

Comment: @dystroy Thanks but I rather change only the color. When I change the text my script does something its not suppose to, thats why I only whant to change the color.

Comment: @Youss You can't change only the color : a style can only be applied to an element, not to a word. That's why you need to make this element.

Comment: @dystroy Im not sure but I think its possible to 'find' a word and make it a var, then change the var. I think Im going to try this. Im working with cookies. When I change the text, the stored data from the cookie is lost.

Comment: @Youss no, you can't do that. The fundamental limit is that the browser can only style elements, not words. But my code works, you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can  do this way but it is not tested:

```
$(function() {
    var color = $('body').text('text');
    color.css("color", "red");
});
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me. I lose dynamicly created data, being replaced with the word 'text'

Comment: @JaiPSah `$('body').text('text')` changes the text of the body to 'text'. See http://api.jquery.com/text/